URL Scheme not working with Expo GO app deployed on android virtual device
I am developing a React Native application with Expo, and during the development phase, I run the application on a virtual Android device with Expo GO (but the issue also occurs on a device connected via USB, as long as the application is launched through Expo GO). This application uses an SSO connection with the opening of a web view and a return with a URL Scheme (containing an access token). Everything works fine with expo-auth-session using, however, despite numerous parameters I have found in the documentation, the URL Scheme is not recognized and does not reopen the application. Indeed, the web view gives an error ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME.
Is it possible to use a custom URL Scheme with an application via Expo GO? Or is a build in App Bundle/APK absolutely necessary? If so, it would be inconvenient as it would be impossible to launch the application with Expo GO, making it less practical!
Has anyone in the React Native community managed to do this?
I added scheme setting in de app.json with my custom url scheme.
